# In this sentence, why is "do" not at the end? Is there a specific rule for this?

Tags: grammar

"Women who are heavy coffee drinkers find fewer errors in the study **than do** less caffeinated women."

Comment: Fewer errors do women who are heavy coffee drinkers find, than do less caffeinated women (find).

Comment: Where did you expect "do" to be? Please [edit] this to clearly explain exactly what you're asking by showing the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's really just a matter of preference.

If you said *"Women who are heavy coffee drinkers find fewer errors in the study than less caffeinated women do."* then there's a potential "parsing error".  When we read a sentence we break it up into smaller chunks of meaning, eg

```
Women 
who are heavy coffee drinkers 
find fewer errors in the study 
than do 
less caffeinated women
```

and so we can comprehend easily that there's a comparison between "women" and "less caffeinated women".

If we put do at the end then it **could** get parsed like so

```
Women 
who are heavy coffee drinkers 
find fewer errors in the study 
than  
less caffeinated women
do   <error!  Must re-read>
```

What this seems to be saying, before we realise our mistake and re-read it, is that the coffee-drinking women are counting two things in the study: the number of errors and the number of "less caffeinated women", and the number of errors is smaller than the number of less caffeinated women *within the study*.  Obviously this doesn't really make sense but you don't necessarily realise that until you get to the end.

A lot of people **wouldn't** fall into the above trap and would get the right meaning first time, but it's a risk nonetheless.

On the other hand, some people might think that *"Women who are heavy coffee drinkers find fewer errors in the study than do less caffeinated women."* is a bit clunky, and awkward, and confusing.  So it's a choice for the writer.

Comment: This is a very sound analysis. The issue can become significant when either comparison is plausible, as in "Women find more children in the study than men who are assigned a similar task." Is the sense of the sentence "Women find more children in the study than men who are assigned a similar task find," or is it "Women find more children in the study than they find men who are assigned a similar task"? In this case, moving _do_ forward in the sentence ("Women find more children in the study than do men who are assigned similar task") prevents the reader from taking the wrong fork in the trail.